# How to show all data in table view during pagination in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Here i had implemented pagination for the table view and items are loaded by using model class but here the loaded items are replacing with the new items and whenever it calls api it returns the new data and old data is overriding on it and displaying only 10 items at a time i am implementing it for first time can anyone help me how to resolve the issue ?

```
func listCategoryDownloadJsonWithURL(listUrl: String) {
        let url = URL(string: listUrl)!
        print(listUrl)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
                    self.listClassModel = ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject])
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        guard let obj = self.listClassModel else { return }
                        let itemsCount = obj.items.count
                        print(itemsCount)
                        for i in 0..<itemsCount {
                            let customAttribute = obj.items[i].customAttribute
                            for j in 0..<customAttribute.count {
                                if customAttribute[j].attributeCode == "image" {
                                    let baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product"
                                    self.listCategoryImageArray.append(baseUrl + customAttribute[j].value)
                                    print(self.listCategoryImageArray)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                        self.collectionView.delegate = self
                        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        self.collectionView.isHidden = false
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning your result data to model array, each time you call your API. This is the reason that your old data is getting replaced with new one. Rather than assigning, you should append the new data to your datasource array.

```
 if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
         self.listClassModel.append(contentsOf: ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject]))
```

Also make sure you initialize your array as an empty array first. (maybe in declaration or viewDidLoad) before calling API.

Comment: I declared an empty array as shown like here but its retuning an error in the mentioned change line  self.listClassModel.append(contentsOf: ModelClass(dict: jsonObj as [String : AnyObject]))  and the error is value of type [string:anyobject] has no member append var listClassModel : [String: AnyObject] = [:]

Comment: var listClassModel = [ModelClass]() this is how an array is instantiated. You are defining an dictionary in above code.

Comment: but I tried like this also var listClassModel = [[String:AnyObject]]() but here also it is showing error that cannot convert value of type 'Model Class' to expected argument type [string:anyobject]

Comment: Why are you defining your array of type array of dictionary? You should define it as array of ModelClass. ModelClass and dictionary are two different type.

Comment: how to declare just tell me bro I am new to swift 3 ?

Comment: var listClassModel = [ModelClass]()

Comment: Remove that line, as your listClassModel is not an optional type. So you can’t unwrap it.

Comment: but I need to get count that so that to filter the data from model class then how to find it ?

Comment: sel.listClassModel.count will just fine.

Comment: but I need not to get listclassmodel.count I need to get its inner items count so that to check inside it

Comment: in table view no. of rows in section  also how to give count ?

Comment: getting error like this  in no. of rows in section https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrOzi.png

Comment: How can list of ModelClass will have have an property of items? You have to fetch individual item via self.listClassModel[index]. As I said, first read the basic of swift. This form is a Q&A not a line by line error resolution.

Comment: I used as u said but not showing any errors but got crashed at no. of rows in section